# Email Service: Filtering quoted text (response history) from message body before saving

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

I have an email service which saves message body to linked Opportunity in the Notes. Although this works, this will save ALL the content from the email including all previous correspondances if they are within the email.

Is there a way I can filter this out before saving to Notes?

Comment: This isn't really a question about salesforce. It's about telling the difference between current text and forwarded/responded text in an email.

Comment: @Dominic How so? Its related the email service within Salesforce. I wanted to know whether there was a function within SF or some apex that could be used to filter out the unwanted text.

Comment: because email contents are a function of "Email", rather than of anything defined by salesforce. I've still answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, but not always, previous text starts with > so in the past we've removed every line that starts > from the email.